# Detrend only $X$ or also $y$ for stationarity?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, arima, stationarity, trend

I'm curious about time series analysis in machine learning.

Naturally, when we use standard techniques like ARIMA we want to remove the trends of the data to introduce stationarity through differencing. Now, it seems like stationary data could also improve a machine learning model.

The question I have is when we remove the trend of a dataset do we only remove the trend of the explanatory variables, or do we also remove the trend of the response variables as well? My gut feeling is we only detrend the explanatory variables - however I'd like some confirmation on this and a reason why this is important.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Stationarity is necessary when forecasting but when you talk about X-Y relationships, this is in the realm of regression, possibly linear regression. There is no need for differencing in the latter.

Comment: @Arun Jose what about in the case of regression with a neural network?

Comment: I see no issue there either.

Comment: @ArunJose [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81271/124589) seemed to have found that detrending was effective. Could you elaborate on why you don't think so?

Comment: The post talks about forecasting, not regression.

Comment: Is the result of a regression-type neural network not a forecast?